# WPF listbox. Skip underscore symbols in strings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some WPF ListBox which is dynamically populating with items. Something like this :

```
ListBox.Items.Add
(new ListBoxItem { Content = new CheckBox { IsChecked = true, Content = "string_string"} );
```

The problem is with checkbox content. It's showing on GUI like "stringstring"...
How to escape the "_" symbols ? (I get strings dynamically)

Comment: You want to see the underline or want to remove it?

Comment: I want to see the underlines on GUI

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add the text in a TextBlock and put that TextBlock inside your Chekbox, TextBlock does not support _ mnemonic characters. Here's what I mean, in xaml, but you can easily convert this to code:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="True">
    <TextBlock>string_string</TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Can I escape "_" characters using "ContentStringFormat" property somehow ?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any way in which you can escape the underscores via the ContentStringFormat. And even if there was a way, escaping the "_" characters in the string means to iterate through all the characters in the string which will be slower than just using a TextBlock.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I wrapped strings in textblocks

Comment: Using
`<ListBox.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="RecognizesAccessKey" Value="False" />
  </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>`
doesn't help, by the way...

Comment: `ContentStringFormat` would indeed help, if the part containing the "_" is part of the format. I had the exact opposite problem and asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48297201).

Answer (score 15):

The default template for the CheckBox contains a ContentPresenter whose **RecognizesAccessKey** is set to true. If the content is a string (which it is in your case), then the ContentPresenter creates an **AccessText** element to display the text. That element hides the underscore until the Alt key is pressed because it will treat it as a mnemonic. You can either retemplate the CheckBox such that its ContentPresenter's RecognizesAccessKey is false or better yet just provide a DataTemplate as the ContentTemplate which contains a TextBlock. If you're not sure if the content will be a string then you can set the ContentTemplateSelector and in code provide a DataTemplate which contains a TextBlock only if the item is a string. e.g.

```
<ListBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="sys:String" x:Key="stringTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource stringTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="A_B" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource stringTemplate}"/>
        <!-- Or use the implicit style to set the ContentTemplate -->
        <CheckBox Content="A_B" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: In case you get a runtime exception telling that the template name was not found in StaticResource (while the designer handles it perfectly), just remove the DataType attribute from the DataTemplate. Not sure why it's there and why it doesn't work, but this helped for me. Otherwise, I like this solution as it seems to be the shortest possible way in WPF to get rid of those absurd access keys in column headers.

Answer (score 7):

Use a double underscore string__string, since in WPF, the _ is the mnemonic character.

Even better, just solve this issue in xaml and create a collection in your view model (or code-behind).

Comment: No way to disable this in other way?

Comment: You can use listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = new CheckBox { IsChecked = true, Content = ("string_string").Replace("_", "__" )} }); instead. This does not involve modification to the actual string.

Comment: And then if I'll want to get string back in some code, I have to remember to make one more replace...Think texblocks is most elegant solution in this way

Comment: Yes, textblock approach is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a DataGrid. Similarly to AndrewS, I added a style for TextBlock, but did not use DataTemplate or ContentTemplate. This way the setters in ColumnHeaderStyle were applied :) However, this solution works only for single underscores, eg. "a_b", but not for "a__b".

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <!-- my setters here do not get overridden -->
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```