# How do I disable Mnemonics in a WPF MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I have dynamic strings appear as the MenuItem's header, which sometimes contains '_'. WPF treats the underscores as signs for mnemonics, but I don't want that. How do I disable that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying all the solutions in the thread [WPF listbox. Skip underscore symbols in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601801/wpf-listbox-skip-underscore-symbols-in-strings), which didn't seem to work on MenuItems, I did this:

```
public class EscapeMnemonicsStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value as string;
        return str != null ? str.Replace("_", "__") : value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you ask a question that you already have a solution for??? That is *not* what this site is for.

Comment: @Sheridan, it is totally allowed to do that... When ever you ask a question, you have the option of answering it before you even post it. If your problem is one that you haven't been able to find anything on, this can be quite useful to future viewers.

Comment: @SuperPrograman, while I disagree with this personally, I have looked at the help pages and now accept that you are correct. Apologies Omer.

Comment: @Omer - Also please post this answer on the link you mentioned. So that it adds value to that answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution is to put your menu text inside a `TextBox` with adjusted properties.

If building your `MenuItem` in code, the it would look like this:

```
var menuItem = new MenuItem();
var menuHeader = new Textbox();
menuHeader.Text = "your_text_here";
menuHeader.IsReadOnly = true;
menuHeader.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
menuHeader.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
menuItem.Header = menuHeader;
menuItem.ToolTip = "your detailed tooltip here";
menuItem.Click += YourEventHandlerHere;
yourMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
```

If your menu is in XAML and it is just the text that is dynamic, it would look like this:

```
<MenuItem Name="menuDynamic" Click="menuDynamic_Click">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBox Name="dynamicMenu"
                 Text="With_Underscore"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0" />
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Then your code behind could dynamically set `dynamicMenu.Text = "what_ever";` when it needed to.