# Why is AccessText not used when using ContentStringFormat?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, controls

When using a string value as `Content` of a ContentControl (like Label), using an `_` inside the string allows using the following letter as access key, like this:

```
<Label Content="Text with _access key"/>
```

or even

```
<Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
```

if Text is a string property containing an `_`.

However, when using `ContentStringFormat` which contains the `_`, it doesn't work any more:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Value}" ContentStringFormat="_Formatted value {0}"/>
```

I have seen in the debugger that no `AccessText` is used in this case.

As a workaround, I have used `AccessText` explicitly:

```
<Label>
  <AccessText Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=_Formatted value {0}"/>
</Label>
```

It works that way but I still want to know why it doesn't when using `ContentStringFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601801/wpf-listbox-skip-underscore-symbols-in-strings) topic will give you some insight about the `AccesText`.

Comment: So it seems `RecognizesAccessKey` does not apply to `ContentStringFormat`. That is unfortunate but I think I can't do much about it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608311) answer was the most helpful in that question. Thanks!